# take data from string response using almofire in swift

Tags: swift

i try to post some data using alamofire.response coming in to string. now how can i fetch data from string response.

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: ["API":"get_blog_list","user_id":"18","page":"1"], encoding: URLEncoding.default).responseString(completionHandler: { (response) in
    guard let datastring = response.result.value else { return }
    print(datastring)
```

my response(datastring) is

```
{
   "success" : "1",
   "totalpage" : "2",
   "blogdata" : [
             {
              "int_glocode" : "18",
              "var_blogtitle" : "ssss",
              "tblogdescription" : "ssssss",
              "var_images" : "http//url",
              "dt_creatdate" : "21-8-2017",
              "flag" : "false"
             }
            {
              "int_glocode" : "19",
              "var_blogtitle" : "ssss",
              "tblogdescription" : "ssssss",
              "var_images" : "http//url",
              "dt_creatdate" : "21-8-2017",
              "flag" : "false"
             }
          ]
}
```

now i want to get data of "var_blogtitle","tblogdescription","var_images"
so i create struct for that

```
struct Data:Decodable {
    var var_image: URL
    var tblogdescription : String
    var var_blogtitle: String

    init(blogdata:[String:Any]) {
        self.var_blogtitle = blogdata["var_blogtitle"] as! String
        self.tblogdescription = blogdata["tblogdescription"] as! String
        self.var_image = blogdata["var_image"] as! URL

    }
}
```

Comment: This JSON is not valid.

Comment: where did i do mistake sir? please answer the valid json

Comment: The closing `]` and a comma between the dictionaries is missing.

Comment: thak you sir. it is my writing mistake. actually that is my response come after post with almofire.

Answer (score -1):

Use this code for reference. But make sure your JSON is valid.

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters ["API":"get_blog_list","user_id":"18","page":"1"], encoding: URLEncoding.default).responseString(completionHandler: { (response) in
        guard let datastring = response.result.value else { return }

        if let data = datastring as? [String: AnyObject] {
            if let data = data["blogdata"] as? NSArray {
                for data in data {
                    if let data = data as? [String: AnyObject] {
                        let var_blogtitle = data["var_blogtitle"] as? String
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: Please don't suggest `NSArray` and a JSON dictionary is `[String:Any]`, not `[String:AnyObject]` in Swift  3+.

Comment: NSArray as [Any] Right?

Comment: No, in this case more specific `[[String:Any]]` or even `[[String:String]]`

Comment: not working. for  response i made struct is ok or nor? i think problem in my struct.

Comment: Are you getting data in for loop, if it getting then parse it properly